# Keeping appended TextViews in place even after switching between activities

Tags: android, textview

I am learning to make a simple SMS app with a little extra functions.
The app sends and receives SMSes beautifully but the one problem I have is when I switch between activities in the app.

Say for example, after I receive the SMS, I click on a button to start a new activity which is essentially a calculator and it brings me to another screen. But when I return back to the SMS page, all the conversation I've had with the other party, namely a second emulator, disappears. Is there any way to fix this?

I'd be happy to put the codes up here if they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [shared preferences. This is a great example.](http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html)